# Microsoft Project Change Show on Board with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-project

In the Microsoft Project application, one is able to turn off the ability to display a Task in the Task Board View so I assume that VBA should have the capability to control ability to display as well. Does anyone know the Property Name that would allow me to turn the display of a specific task on and off in the Task Board View. The column, Show on Board, in the Project application Gantt Chart View that controls the display of tasks is shown in the provided image.

I've searched the Microsoft Project Object Model but am not able to find a "Show on Board" property in the Task Object.

[MS-Project Gantt Chart View - Show on Board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8k0E.png)

Comment: David Althausen I think maybe you assume too much. There are many things you can do in Project that simply do not have a method in VBA to replicate. However, in your example, have you considered using a filter to turn tasks "on" and "off"?

Comment: @john-project it's possible I assume too much, however, I know that MS's online Object Model documentation of the Task Board is not up to date. I did look in the Object Browser but no properties stood out to me so it seemed worth asking. I could do a filter but that is a last resort since then I will have to perform custom filtering to layer filters on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to "hide" tasks from the Gantt Table in MS Project is remove them from the current filter. There is no hide method to hide tasks like you can hide rows in Excel.

I recommend checking out the [SetAutoFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.setautofilter), [FilterEdit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.filteredit), and [FilterApply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.filterapply) methods.

For example, you could use the FilterApply Method to do something like this:

```
Application.SetAutoFilter FieldName:="Flag1", FilterType:=pjAutoFilterCustom, Test1:="Equals", Criteria1:="Yes"
```

That line will filter the active project for only tasks that are marked Yes in the Flag1 field.

Comment: I'm trying to hide tasks in Task Board view, not the Gantt view. The place to do so in the application can be found in the Gantt view hence the picture I added.